# how to specify start and end date for dynamic dates in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I have written query as below in my java file

```
String query = "select STATUS, COUNT(*) as NO_OF_INCIDENT from  DASHBOARD_INCIDENT where SYSTEM = ? AND TRUNC(STARTDATE_PLAN) between TRUNC(?) and TRUNC(?) group by STATUS order by STATUS asc";
```

and trying to set dates as below

```
ps.setString(1, AppName);
        ps.setString(2, startdate);
        ps.setString(3, enddate);
```

This is not working for me, pls help me in correcting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you either:

- use `ps.setDate()` instead, or
- keep `ps.setString()` but change your statement to
  `... between TRUNC(to_date(?, 'yourformat')) and TRUNC(to_date(?, 'yourformat')) ...`, where `'yourformat'` is format string like 'yyyy-mm-dd', according to your actual string format.

Answer (score 0):

- Use something like below:-

> WHERE trunc(STARTDATE_PLAN) BETWEEN to_date(?,'MM-DD-YYYY') AND
>   TO_DATE(?,'MM-DD-YYYY')

- Avoid using TRUNC function STARTDATE_PLAN, its inefficient.